# Is there a way to use if/else on Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm discovering selenium and writing a simple code to scrape some data. However, where some sites do have certain classes, others do not. So I want to have something like

```
restaurant_description = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_2YIdLB").text
if restaurant_description = TRUE
print(restaurant_description)
else 
pass
```

Is there something like this? Or do I have to use a "common exception"?

Answer (score 0):

***You can do something like:***

```
try:
    elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Create Activity')
    if elem.is_displayed() and elem.is_enabled():
       
        elem.text # this will get the text
        print("Text is found!")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("...")
```

Comment: If I try something like that, I get this: IndentationError: unexpected indent
Also, I don't want it to print something if there is an exception, I just don't want an error when it's not there. So, does this restaurant have a description? Nice, let's print is. Doesn't it have a description? Just go on

Comment: You know why `IndentationError` occurs ? And if this is what you do not need than please explain more, The exception handling is a good practice to do `code`